# Sharepoint Image Rotator

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Within a content editor webpart, or any other way; how can I make images rotate based on the month? Is this a matter of putting javascript right into the html editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several image slide shows that you can use, I recommend you Nivo Slider http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/
To set up this you will have always to use some custom html code on a webpart, and have to insert a script call to the slider on the master page.

Here you have some examples of the slider running on sharepoint themes 
http://www.bindtuning.com/cms/sharepoint/sharepoint-2013/theme/InvisibleDog/page/Sliders/customize